# NuGet private feed not updating DownloadCount

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I have set up a small test Nuget private repository on my machine following [this guide](http://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds#creating-remote-feeds).

Everything is working perfectly and I can publish packages, update versions, download them etc. The only problem is that the `DownloadCount` of my packages is always 0 regardless of how many times I download it.

I downloaded NuGet source but could not find a place where this value is updated. Moreover, nuget does not seem to use any DB technology so probably the feed is just generated on demand from the contents of the Packages folder.

Does anyone have any idea if this is a known issue or if it's a problem in my setup or if I should just add some code to the server to record downloads myself?

Thanks!

Comment: As we have discovered creating our own private server, you'd have to implement the persistence yourself. If you don't want to write it yourself, you can download [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget) which already handles this.

Comment: Strangely enough, even in ProGet the download count is stuck at 0. Besides, from VS the list of packages is empty (although it works ok from the console). I can see the DB upping the download count (not consistently I have to say) but the interface and the feed always report 0.

Comment: Interesting, ProGet package metadata is heavily cached for performance reasons, so it's most likely not refreshing the cache unless something in the package directory changes (that's what triggers a refresh). I suppose we could decrease the length between forced refreshes, but since only the download is mutable it seems unnecessary since it's more a UI nice-to-have than anything else (for private repos anyway).

Comment: Agreed, but sometimes it seems that the DB does not update as well (mostly when downloading a previous version). I wil investigate more. Anyway, it is not only a nice UI feature, people may use it to decide which package version to delete from the server based on downloads (although I reckon it is not a very frequent use case).

Comment: Yup, apparently when "updating" package the Download Count (of the newer version) is not updated. Dunno if this is intended or not. Moreover, when exploring packages the NuGet UI in VS always shows "No package from the current source". Please note that I removed the default NuGet connector.

Comment: Did you find a solution eventually?

Comment: Nope, I decided to live with it... I could try to upgrade the NuGet server but at the moment the server itself is a bit critical so I'll check in the future.

Comment: @Tallmaris anything new on this?

Comment: Nope, I left things as they are and decideded not to worry. It's a nuisance but there are worse...

Comment: I believe it's actually the [NuGet Gallery](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery) that takes care of updating the download count. See e.g. [this issue](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/252).

Answer (score 0):

NuGet.Server based web sites are simply a front-end exposing an OData feed on top of a file share. There's no real database behind it, no indexing, no auditing, tracing, metrics or statistics, or any of that kind of stuff.

You could build it yourself, or take a look at alternatives such as [MyGet](https://www.myget.org), ProGet, Artifactory, etc.