# How to track packages downloads on Nuget.Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget

We're using private Nuget repository for serving packages in intranet environment. Is it possible to track what packages are downloaded to create basic statistics? For example which packages were downloaded the most, etc.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448071/nuget-private-feed-not-updating-downloadcount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you have an ASP.NET application which uses the NuGet.Server package.

Then it would be quite easy to add some logging. You can decorate the PackageService:

```
public class MyPackageService : IPackageService
{
    public MyPackageService(PackageService packageService)
    {
        _PackageService = packageService;
    }

    private readonly PackageService _PackageService;

    public void CreatePackage(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        _PackageService.CreatePackage(context);
    }

    public void DeletePackage(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        _PackageService.DeletePackage(context);
    }

    public void DownloadPackage(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        // LOG HERE
        Log(context);
        _PackageService.DownloadPackage(context);
    }

    public void PublishPackage(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        _PackageService.PublishPackage(context);
    }
}
```

and then change Routes.cs to rebind to `MyPackageService`.

```
public static class NuGetRoutes {

    public static void Start() {
        NinjectBootstrapper.Kernel.Rebind<IPackageService>().To<MyPackageService>();
        MapRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: You are correct! (I don't know why `CreatePackageService` is even there if it's not called.) Rebinding the kernel seems to work though. I've fixed the change to `NuGetRoutes.Start()` above.

Comment: What version of Nuget.Server are you using? It seems that it stopped working (debugger not hit my class) again with Nuget.Server 2.7.0. I'm confused. :(

Comment: I'm using 2.7.0 too. The NuGetRoutes.Start will only happen when the web application is starting. You need to restart your webserver for any changes to be taken into effect.